# Data Refresh After component render in UseQuery of react-admin

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, react-admin

i use useQuery for showing list item, i need to Button for Refresh my requests how i can use  useRefresh  for this work?

this is my Code:

```
const {data,total,loading,error} = useQuery({

  type: 'GET_LIST',

  resource: 'requests',

  payload: {

    pagination: { page: page, perPage: perPage },

    sort: { field: 'createdAt', order: 'DESC' },

    filter: {restaurants_id:restaurants_id,createdAt:date}

  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { useRefresh } from 'react-admin';
...
const refresh = useRefresh();
...
refresh();
```